# How to execute a python package in zip format

Tags: python, python-packaging

I want to create a `python zipfile` and execute it.

What I do is, first, create the following directories and source files:

**Directory tree**

```
pkgtest/
└── pkga
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py
```

**__main__.py**:

```
print("SADASD")
```

**__init__.py**: empty

At this point, I can do:

```
python pkga
```

and it works, but if I run the following commands:

```
python -m zipfile -c pkga.zip pkga   # This generates a pkga.zip file
python pkga.zip
```

And I obtain the following error:

`/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in 'pkga.zip'`

**What am I missing?**

### EDIT

Doing this:

```
python3 -m zipapp pkga
```

and then

```
python3 pkga.pyz
```

it works.

However, according to [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rochacbruno/ed19c5d9ba9bb50391a2) it should be enough with a normal zip file. Is this correct?

Comment: just to make sure: `python -m zipfile -l pkga.zip` confirms that both files are in the zip file?

Comment: @Stef yes, it does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__main__.py` file must be in the top level dir of the zip file, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_path):

> (e.g. a zipfile containing a top-level `__main__.py` file).

You must run

```
python -m zipfile -c ../pkga.zip .
```

from inside the pkga directory. When you run `python -m zipfile -c pkga.zip pkga` you create a zip file with a directory pkga with the files inside it but python looks for `__main__.py` in the top level dir of the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`zipapp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html) module to create the ZIP archive.

```
python -m zipapp pkga
python pkga.pyz
```

The `.pyz` file is a ZIP archive.